# SQL How to extract only 2 columns result set with 5 columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table which has 5 columns providing employee ID and 1 column is a primary key for the table. The standard employee ID value is 6 digit alpha numerical. But not all these columns will provide the right employee ID. I need to extract only 2 columns of right employee ID based on the precedence of the EMPID1 ,EMPID2, EMPID3 EMPID4 and EMPID5.

Table illustration:

| Pkey | EMPID1 | EMPID2 | EMPID3 | EMPID4 | EMPID5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | AB1111 | NULL | 111 | CD1234 | 1 |
| 222 | NULL | XY5678 | 12 | ABC | MN3456 |
| 333 | 11 | NULL | UI | GH0987 | HI5432 |
| 444 | WA9087 | MT4378 | DG1287 | JE2435 | PT9825 |

Expected Output:

| Pkey | EMPID11 | EMPID22 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | AB1111 | CD1234 |
| 222 | XY5678 | MN3456 |
| 333 | GH0987 | HI5432 |
| 444 | WA9087 | MT4378 |

Comment: Please tag your database system and show us your try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `COALESCE` and `IFF` :

```
  SELECT Pkey, COALESCE(
                 IFF( LENGTH(EMPID1) = 6, EMPID1 , NULL ), 
                 IFF( LENGTH(EMPID2) = 6, EMPID2 , NULL ),
                 IFF( LENGTH(EMPID3) = 6, EMPID3 , NULL ),
                 IFF( LENGTH(EMPID4) = 6, EMPID4 , NULL ), 
                 IFF( LENGTH(EMPID5) = 6, EMPID5 , NULL )
             ) as EMPID11,
             COALESCE(
                 IFF( LENGTH(EMPID1) = 6 AND EMPID11 <> EMPID1, EMPID1 , NULL ), 
                 IFF( LENGTH(EMPID2) = 6 AND EMPID11 <> EMPID2, EMPID2 , NULL ),
                 IFF( LENGTH(EMPID3) = 6 AND EMPID11 <> EMPID3, EMPID3 , NULL ),
                 IFF( LENGTH(EMPID4) = 6 AND EMPID11 <> EMPID4, EMPID4 , NULL ), 
                 IFF( LENGTH(EMPID5) = 6 AND EMPID11 <> EMPID5, EMPID5 , NULL )
             ) as EMPID12
  FROM mytable;
```

The value of `EMPID11` must be excluded from `EMPID12`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Pkey,
   COALESCE(
    IFF(LEN(EMPID1) = 6, EMPID1, NULL),
    IFF(LEN(EMPID2) = 6, EMPID2, NULL),
    ...
    IFF(LEN(EMPID5) = 6, EMPID5, NULL)  
   ) AS EMPID11,
   COALESCE(
    IFF(LEN(EMPID5) = 6, EMPID5, NULL),
    IFF(LEN(EMPID4) = 6, EMPID4, NULL),
    ...
    IFF(LEN(EMPID1) = 6, EMPID1, NULL)
   ) AS EMPID22
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string and array functions

```
 select *, 
        array_compact([empid1,empid2,empid3,empid4,empid5]) as ids_array,
        array_to_string(ids_array,',') as ids_array_str,
        regexp_extract_all(ids_array_str,'[^,]{6}') as ids_matches,
        ids_matches[0]::varchar as empid6,
        ids_matches[1]::varchar as empid7
 from t;
```